# ¿Qué componente me recomiendan utilizar para reemplazar un AutoGrowInput en ReactNative?

Tags: react-native

Buen día, el objetivo es reemplazar este componente AutoGrowInput, ya que he encontrado un serie de problemas en el e incluso mas relevantes en iOS, lo que veo que no es muy buena practica seguir utilizándolo, que componente me sugieren que sea nativo para su reemplazo.

componente actual:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/input-autogrow

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor consulta [ask]. Tu pregunta pide recomendaciones y en consecuencia dará lugar a opiniones como respuesta. Por ello muy posiblemente sea cerrada. Te sugiero llevara a [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) donde muy seguramente recibirá una respuesta pertinente.

Answer (score 0):

para solucionar el reemplazar este componente opte por utilizar el componente nativo de react native [TextInput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput)